# is it possible to make a PHP SOAP request to a java web service?

Tags: php

I have a URL : 'http://myurl.com/foo/bar.jws' I am attempting to make a SOAP connection through PHP to this URL but it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something?

```
<?php
try { $soapObject = new SoapClient('http://myurl.com/foo/bar.jws'); }
catch(Exception $e) { die('SOAP connection failed: ' .$e->getMessage()); }
?>
```

I am getting this error:

```
SOAP connection failed: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://myurl.com/foo/bar.jws' : failed to load external entity "http://myurl.com/foo/bar.jws"
```

Comment: Yes. SOAP is a standard. Any client that is compliant with the standard should be able to use it regardless of the language. Your problem appears to be a connection issue. Perhaps you have a firewall or the URL is incorrect.

Comment: turned out to be a mixture of needing authentication and a bad url. thanks for the help!